# How to recognize whether the string is regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have an input which gets a statement from the user. According with the usage of my program, users can enter a character or a regular expression. After filling this input, users have to fill a second input that is the replacement text.

The problem is, user can type `.` and this is equivalent to a regular expression, which matches any character.

Does the below code work? Or, what's the solution?

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if( m.Success )
   // it's regex
else
  // it's not regex
```

Comment: Impossible, since certain strings, even if they constituted valid REGEX patterns, may not be intended for REGEX use, and you wouldn't know whether this was the case or not.

Comment: Give them sepereate textboxes or a checkbox. Defining a specific format to recognize reqular expressions will always have too much exceptions where it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't*.

Let's look at how Visual Studio solves this problem:

[image]

As you can't tell whether or not the user intended the content to be a regular expression, the designers allow the user to choose, giving the user complete control over how they want the search to be performed. If you want it to be plain text (the default), just hit Find Next. Otherwise, you can tailor your search using the additional options.

*Well, you kind of can

The other approach to this problem is to assume the user meant to search using every technique you support, and filter the results; grouped by "Plain Text" matches, and "Regular Expression" matches. This is less efficient but could be considered more user friendly as the user doesn't actively have to choose any options. So you first search by just plain text, and return those matches under the heading "Plain Text Matches", and then search assuming the string is a regular expression, and return those matches under the heading "Regular Expression Matches"

Once you have displayed these to the user, they can choose which one they actually meant for the replace.

Comment: Let's consider Google's search rule. What if I want to search `You can't*`

Comment: @miqbal - I believe that's more of a design decision on behalf of the guys at Google. The majority of people executing a search will not know what a regular expression is, so they never decide to cater for it. There is nothing stopping you from trying both types of search, and show what the results of each would be to the end user - they could then choose which one they wanted, but it still involves a decision by the end user. So either they choose the replace type first, or you search and replace both ways for them, and allow them to choose which result they actually intended.

Comment: But the people who use Visual Studio know regexp, highly.

Comment: @miqbal Some of them, anyway ;-) The point is here that by asking the user to choose the search type up front, you potentially simplify your problem and can optimize the search accordingly. It's a fairly standard way of doing it because it makes things simpler for the implementer. The default is plain text searching because the majority of the time, people will want this type of searching. Also remember that searching is a very different problem to searching and replacing. Google's searching for text and relevancy, something a regexp could make very, very difficult.

Answer (score 5):

## You can't read the user's mind!

If the user types in `...?`, you have no way of knowing whether they want to match a literal `"...?"`, or match 2-3 characters using it as a regex.

If I search for `hello?`, I might not expect to match `"hell"`. *But I might be doing it intentionally*. **You can't know if you don't ask**.

Give them a checkbox!

Comment: Calm down :) Asking to the user was my first way.